# How to remove legend at the bottom of chartjs doughnuts

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to remove all default labels from chartjs doughnut charts but the one at the bottom doesn't seem to go away

There was initially one legend at the  top but I managed to hide that ut now I'm faced with labels at the bottom which completely ruin the chart

here's my options property in my config

```
options: {
    cutoutPercentage: 80,
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
        enabled: false,
    },
}
```

I want all labels and legends to be gone completely so I can define my one with HTML, CSS and custom javascript

Here's a screenshot of what's happened

[messed up chart that makes me want to cry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTNhN.png)

Comment: That doesn't look like a legend, it looks like an axis. Which version of Chart.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using chart.js 2.8.0, installed using npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have some global settings or other code that is causing the x-axis to be displayed, as it is not configured in your options above and is not the default.

I [put together a sample chart](https://jsfiddle.net/6pq3ebLn/) that shows the x-axis being displayed similar to yours.

[image]

If you turn this off in your options, that should no longer be shown. You can toggle that setting to show/not show in the demo to see the difference.

```
options: {
    cutoutPercentage: 80,
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{ display: false }] // <-- add this
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude, you are a freaking genius.
I checked all my files and I did see a global configuration that was meant for line and bar charts but I applied it globally like a noob